# Happy new year!

Tags: discussion

I don't know which timezone you're in and whether it is already New Year for you.

Anyway, I wish you all the very best in the new year 2014, best of health for you and your whole families, perhaps especially the younger members. *May all your dreams but one come true, for what is life without a dream?*

May this community stay as friendly and helpful as it is right now. I hope we attract more people to share the knowledge and, which perhaps is even more important, to ask good helpful questions.

*Sorry to break meta rules. Best wishes once again!*

Comment: From Japan, あけましておめでとうございます！

Comment: Umm. . . on this occasion, I think Rules Schmoolz should apply.  lol - thanks and happy new year to you too.

Comment: I hate to be a grinch, but this really should be closed, lest it become a [broken window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128233/166646).

Answer (score 1):

#### Thank you Dariusz! Also from me a *happy new year* to all.

**How do parents of toddlers celebrate,** knowing that the day starts at 06:00 as usual?

We've made ourselves comfy in our home cinema. The choice of the evening is *Sherlock Holmes* accompanied by some bubbles and some salmon snacks. We'll try to get some sleep before midnight, and hope the kids won't be too bothered by the fireworks.

*See you next year!*

[image: Godt nytår!]

Comment: It's 2014 for me and we're having our first feeding this year;) Our evening was similar, except it was two episodes of Studio 60 and a bit less comfy environment - nice chairs!:) A good evening still.

Comment: We also watched Sherlock!! Too funny.